# Can I convert malloc allocated variable containing charachers into file

Tags: c, file, memory-management

Can I convert malloc allocated space which is pointed to by pointer variable into file for example

```
 char*  ptr = (char*) malloc(size);
```

after writing something to memory can I add it as file on filesystem so it appear on my some folder. how can I do this?

System is linux

Comment: You can _write_ it to a file.

Comment: @tkausl I was thinking of implementing my own data structure. Can you share with me url of source file containing `File` struct?

Comment: You have to define and create your own file format or you could use an already established file format which fits your program.

Comment: @paladin can file format take the form of struct with members (like name and content). if yes then how can I attach it to file system. is there any header file of ext4 that contains declaration of that kind of struct. but also more importantly what is content member and name member be specified exactly so it can be recognized by ext4 file system as a file. I think its a ok enough question if you please consider it to answer.

Comment: @paladin I just want to learn more about files and file system but just using predefined linux syscalls beat that purpose. and is there less well known syscall or linux feature which is vital for attaching file to file system that u may know please share.

Comment: @Alex A file is "just" an accumulation of bits and bytes, of ones and zeroes. I suggest you search and read about the definition of the ext4 filesystem. In modern operating systems, which don't allow direct hardware access, you must use syscalls, everything else is prohibited. If you want to learn something more elementary, I suggest you create a virtual machine, install a copy of _DOS_ or maybe even up to _Windows Millennium Edition_ and write a program for those operating systems, because they allow full hardware access. Otherwise you may read about Linux kernel development, handling files.

Comment: @Alex PS the only way to access hardware in a more direct way within modern protected mode operating systems, is to write a driver. So you may try to write a filesystem driver for example. But this stuff is not easy. The easiest filesystem you may write is probably fat12, which is used for floppy disks.